# Round up decimals and print zero's

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

I want to make this script round up values to 3 decimals.(1.1234 tp 1.123 etc.).

However, `.toFixed(3)` does not do the job, because I need this script to print every value in format `*.***` - including 1 and 0 (1.000, 0.000)

`.toFixed()` rounds up 1.000 to simple 1.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EfYev/9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fruits = {
        apple: {
            apple: 1,
            banana: 0.5,
            pineapple: 8
        },
        banana: {
            apple: 2,
            banana: 1,
            pineapple: 16
        },
        pineapple: {
            apple: 0.125,
            banana: 0.0625,
            pineapple: 1
        }
    };

    function showTab(name) {
        $('div.fruit').hide();
        var $div = $('#' + name).show();
        var number = parseInt($('.number').val(), 0);
        $('span', $div).each(function () {
            $(this).text(($(this).data('val') * number).toFixed(3));
        });
    }

    $('.update').click(function () {
        var vals = {
            apple: 0,
            banana: 0,
            pineapple: 0
        };

        $('.dropdown').each(function () {
            var fruitVal = $(this).prev('.number').val();
            if (fruits[$(this).val()]) {
                vals.apple += fruitVal * fruits[$(this).val()].apple;
                vals.banana += fruitVal * fruits[$(this).val()].banana;
                vals.pineapple += fruitVal * fruits[$(this).val()].pineapple;
            }
        });

        $('.apple').text(vals.apple);
        $('.banana').text(vals.banana);
        $('.pineapple').text(vals.pineapple);
        $('.values').show();
    });

    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? My browsers returns 0.01.toFixed(5) as "0.01000"

Answer (score 1):

You can't print the trailing zeros in javascript using integers or floats, you have to use strings and pad them with zeros, something like :

```
var n = 1.1234,
    l = n.toString().split('.').pop().length;

n = pad( n.toFixed(3), l ); // rounds the number and pads it with zeros

function pad(numb, length) {
    numb = numb.toString();
    while(numb.split('.').pop().length < length) {
        numb = numb + '0';
    }
    return numb;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MFf32/)

Another way would be to leverage the fact that toFixed converts to a string :

```
function roundWithZeros(numb, decimals) {
    var length = numb.toString().split('.').pop().length;
    numb = numb.toFixed(decimals);
    numb = (+numb).toFixed(length)
    return numb;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MFf32/1/)